# gradle protobuf plugin not functioning

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using the below mentioned protobuf gradle plugin in one project where its working fine but when I referenced the same plugin in a different project, 'gradle clean' is consistently giving me the error copied below:

relevant parts of build.grade (v3.4)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf' 

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
  //      classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.9"
    //    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.4'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
    }
}

def grpcVersion = '1.1.2'

dependencies {
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
}


protobuf {
    protoc {
        Artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            Artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                // To generate deprecated interfaces and static bindService method,
                // turn the enable_deprecated option to true below:
                option 'enable_deprecated=false'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**error when I run gradle clean**

```
* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/xyz/xyz/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/xyz/xyz/build.gradle': 102: you tried to assign a value to the class 'org.gradle.api.component.Artifact'
   @ line 102, column 9.
             Artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0'
             ^

  build file '/xyz/xyz/build.gradle': 106: you tried to assign a value to the class 'org.gradle.api.component.Artifact'
   @ line 106, column 13.
                 Artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
```

I have tried protobuf plugins 0.8.0. and 0.8.1 but both give the same error.  v0.8.0 works as is in a different project.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this further would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `artifact`, not `Artifact`. The latter is a class that you try to assign to which will not work, the former is a property you assign to.