# protoc ^ Unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers

I am trying to follow [this example](https://docs.tendermint.com/master/tutorials/kotlin.html), and I've read numerous SoF and have tried [countless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186174/gradle-protobuf-plugin-not-functioning) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721833/having-troubles-configuring-protobuf-in-my-gradle-kotlin-project) of this, including [straight from](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin) the [official plugin page](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/blob/master/examples/stub/build.gradle.kts), but I continue to run into problems building a simple protobuf app

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc // here my editor gives a red ___ to .protobuf.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.google.protobuf")

plugins {
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.18"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.31"

    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))

    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}


protobuf { // my editor knows nothing about this
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:0.8.14"
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "15"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass.set("io.example.AppKt")
}
```

Error:

```sh
* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 50:     protoc {
               ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                   public fun ProtobufConfigurator.protoc(action: ExecutableLocator.() -> Unit): Unit defined in com.google.protobuf.gradle

1 error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the statement `import com.google.protobuf.gradle.protobuf` first, but I'm not sure it can fix your issue.

There is an example project in the `protobuf-gradle-plugin` repository which is expected to work fine, I think that it can be helpful for you. they are written in Kotlin DSL also. please refer.

https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/blob/master/examples/exampleKotlinDslProject/build.gradle.kts